# how to convert vector to list in scheme

Tags: scheme

how to convert vector to list in scheme?
There are almost no procedures on vector.

```
  '#(1 2)
```

There is something like car or cdr like in list?
Thanks

Comment: "convert to string" as in "print to string", or as in "turn each number into a character with an ascii code like this number", or as in "make a string "12" from #(1 2) and I don't care about the algorithm"?

Comment: Heh, you (almost) named the function you need in this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you mean, this?

```
(apply string-append
       (map number->string
            (vector->list '#(1 2))))
=> "12"
```

**UPDATE**

Ooops, you just changed the question. Then it was a lot simpler:

```
(vector->list '#(1 2))
=> '(1 2)
```

Comment: [R5RS, section 6.3.6](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.6): "Like list constants, vector constants must be quoted" (in particular, there are implementations like Chicken that will actually treat unquoted vector literals as an error).